# psycopg2-binary fails to install when installing it with pipenv

Tags: python-3.x, django, pip, pipenv

I am having trouble installing psycopg2-binary (A postgreSQL backend dependecy) in my django project when i use the pipenv utility. However, it installs without any problems if i manually create a virtual environment and use `pip install` to install it.

**Here is what I am getting in the terminal**

---

```
(django-project-FDld66dG) chilusoft@vortex:~/PycharmProjects/django-project$ pipenv install -r requirements.txt 
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project.
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile…
Pipfile.lock (9e16cc) out of date, updating to (79ab59)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
lf.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 174, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 222, in get_legacy_dependencies
    result = reqset._prepare_file(self.finder, ireq, ignore_requires_python=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/req/req_set.py", line 644, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/req/req_set.py", line 134, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/req/req_install.py", line 435, in run_egg_info
    call_subprocess(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/utils/__init__.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(
pip9.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmpbix8dadtbuild/psycopg2-binary/
```

I do not want to use pip, but would rather use pipenv, what can I do in order to sort this out?

Comment: Please notice that one of the points of using `pipenv` is using `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` for managing dependencies not `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I know that. The reason why I am using the requirements file is that this project was formally using pip and pipenv is ble to recognize the requirements.txt file and then make the needed Pipfile and Pipfile.lock. But would that be the reason why installation is failing?